# Model category with one object

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

A category with one object is a monoid. A groupoid with one object is a group. A linear category with one object is a ring.

This may be a trivial question, but what is a *model category* with one object? Do such things occur "in nature"?

Answer (score 3):

A model category has all limits and colimits (or at least all finite limits and colimits, depending on your definition).  In particular, it has an initial object, so if there is only one object, it is initial and has only the identity map as an endomorphism.  So a model category with one object is just the terminal category which can trivially be seen to admit a unique model structure (the identity must be a weak equivalence, fibration, and cofibration).

Comment: Damn, it was an even stupider question than I thought. So I guess this means there are no model categories with a finite number of objects?

Comment: Well, any complete and cocomplete category admits a model structure where weak equivalences are just isomorphisms and every map is a fibration and cofibration.  In particular this applies to any finite lattice.  I don't know off the top of my head whether a finite lattice can have a model structure different from this one.

Comment: To add gently to the last comment, any bicomplete category $\mathcal{C}$ (finite or otherwise) trivially becomes a model category by declaring any one of $Cof$, $Fib$, $We$ to be the isomorphisms, and the other two to consist of all the morphisms in  $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: On the other hand, there certainly are 'non-trivial' finite model categories, and they tend to be quite important for constructing counterexamples. An example of one such is constructed by Reid Barton [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325383/counter-example-to-the-existence-of-left-bousfield-localization-of-combinatorial/325390#325390), for instance.